# Trying to power a 12 V LED underglow system using PWM signal from dome light

Tags: led, pwm, automotive, 12v, low-pass

I've learned a lot from the brilliant minds on this forum so far, and I think I've narrowed my original question a bit.

I'm trying to create an entry light effect in my car using my LED underglow wired to the dome light circuit, however the problem I'm running into is that the dome light operates on a PWM circuit with a peak of 12 V, a frequency of 120Hz, and duty cycle of 60%.

I know a little about electrical circuits and can follow wiring diagrams, but I'm over my head trying to design a circuit with either a low pass RC filter, a MOSFET, relay, or other configuration to try to power the LED lights using the dome light circuit, as that is the behavior I would like the lights to mimic.

It does not have to have the fade effect, and I'm OK with a little bit of flicker, but I would like the lights to come on when there is either a constant 12 V signal from the dome light (which is the case with doors open), or with the above mentioned PWM circuit (which is in effect with the door closed and hitting the unlock button or when closing and locking the door, fading 3 seconds after locking).

My thought is to use a low pass filter to create a constant voltage around 7 V, which may or may not be enough to power the LEDs, though a bit dimmer (which is fine), or I may need to trigger a relay with that 7 V current to supply 12 V from the battery.  Any other simpler solutions would be great if someone can help with specifics of what I would need.

I will also have these on a switched circuit powered by the +12 V ACC while the car is on (this is already wired and working fine), but the circuits would be separated by diodes to prevent back feeding.

EDIT:  See below for a schematic of what I think might work and what I can build, but please see if you can at least figure out what I'm trying to do with this and suggest improvements.

Basically I'm trying to design a simple low pass RC filter with a resistor and capacitor (4.7kohm and 22uF are values I got from an online calculator) to convert the 12V, 120Hz, 60% PWM signal to a relatively constant 7.2V DC signal that will trigger a relay (4.5V-12V input trigger) to provide an alternate 12V source to the LED controller from the battery.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but any reason you can't run the LEDs directly off the PWM signal? They'll flicker but you said you don't care about that.

Comment: Tried that, and they flash on once and go off.  I'm assuming it has to do with the circuitry in the LED control box needing a constant 12V signal.